# Failed to initialize x11 resources

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I'm getting a runtime error while executing

```
win=dlib.image_window()
```

on google collab. I've already uninstalled the dlib library that was on collab by default, installed libx11-dev and re-installed dlib on the collab using

```
!pip install dlib --verbose
```

command on collab. Still I'm getting the run time error. What should I do now?

Traceback:

```
RuntimeError  Traceback (most recent call last)

 <ipython-input-5-36dc2db7a7d7> in <module>()
----> 1 win=dlib.image_window()

RuntimeError: Failed to initialize X11 resources
```

Comment: Please list the traceback error. Thanks!

Comment: RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-5-36dc2db7a7d7> in <module>()
----> 1 win=dlib.image_window()

RuntimeError: Failed to initialize X11 resources

Comment: Collab runs on a remote server, with no X11 running, this won't work at all on such setup, don't try to use libraries that use X11 in a remote server.

Comment: Matias, should I use jupyter notebook instead of google collab then? But I don't have any gpu in my laptop? Would that be a problem for the dlib?